# Why did Newt have champagne on his counter?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

When they escape and get into his kitchen, one of Newt’s baby Nifflers climbs onto a champagne bottle Newt had on his counter and ends up popping off the cork, going flying along with it.

[image: Baby Niffler riding champagne cork]

But, why did Newt have champagne on his counter to begin with? He doesn’t seem to be the type of person who drinks it or has guests often, so champagne seems like an odd thing for him to have.

Comment: I loved this scene. The baby nifflers were probably the best part of the film :-)

Comment: @Valorum I loved it too, the baby Nifflers certainly were adorable! :-)

Comment: I had this exact question.  It seemed so out of place, I couldn't enjoy any of the cuteness... :(

Comment: But champagne is tasty and fizzy.

Comment: Baby nifflers are savage

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not proof-positive, but we do see Newt in the vicinity of some champagne at his recent book launch. It seems likely that he (or possibly Bunty,  anticipating/hoping that he'd be [in the mood to party](https://media2.giphy.com/media/rjkJD1v80CjYs/giphy.gif?cid=3640f6095c085f99426e734945ac1906)!) liberated a spare bottle while he was there.

[image]

[image]

As to whether Newt drinks *per se*, Queenie seems to be able to rustle up a bottle of what's described as "[English Butterbeer](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2018/11/21/behind-the-magic-of-fantastic-beasts-the-crimes-of-grindelwald-with-graphics-duo-minalima/)" from within Newt's kitchen cupboards. Since Queenie and Jacob have only just arrived in the country it seems unlikely that they've had time to stop at a local off-licence, strongly implying that it belongs to Newt.

[image]

Comment: even people who don't drink often keep bottles of decent wine and/or champagne around in case an upscale party breaks out.

Comment: @KutuluMike - Newt doesn't seem the 'upscale party' sort. That would explain why the bottle is gathering dust in his kitchen

Comment: could also have been a housewarming gift

Comment: @KutuluMike - Although he's only recently returned from overseas, I see no sign of this being a new house

Comment: @Valorum - the nifflers planned on the upscale party, not Newt